# Refer to a vaiable cell in another worksheet by referencing the worksheet's name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been looking for a similar question on the net, but could not find any thing possibly near to it. Here is my problem:

There are some worksheets in my workbook. Say "first", "second" etc. 
I have a table on "first" with some rows/columns. In the first cell (left side) in each row, there is the name of a worksheet. Let's say: 
Cells(2, 1).Value = "second" :Also, the CellValue of A2 is "second".
Cells(3, 1).Value = "third"  :Also, the CellValue of A3 is "third". etc.

Now the value of Cell "first".B2 should be the vale of the cell (let's say) "second".P3 (on "second"). I believe the formula for this matter could be:
=INDIREKT("'"&A2&"'"&"!P3")

That works perfectly fine. My problem begins, when a column is inserted on or removed from "second" and therefore the Value(P3) moves.
How can I make my code flexible, so it automatically updates itself?

Thanx for the answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Indirect(). If you use VBA, as the `Cells(2, 1).Value = "second"` suggests, you don't need a text reference to a cell `P3`. It should be possible to use some other business logic to arrive at the cell address that holds the desired value. Without more information about your spreadsheet structure and intentions of the VBA, it's hard to be more specific, though.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. But no, in this case I am not using VBA even if some parts suggested I do.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It's always the same thing, isn't it?! Just as I posted my question, I found the solution myself. But for those interested:

The easiest way is to use cell names. In this case, I would name P3 like TEST and my code looks like this: =INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'"&"!TEST")

This makes it dynamic or flexible to changes.